# Comparing two arrays. Wrong return value (1)

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return, program-entry-point

I made this method that compares the numbers of two arrays and then returns how many numbers are equal to each other, but no matter how many numbers are equal, the method returns the value 1 every time.
(both arrays are the same length).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a []  = {1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 13};
    int b []  = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

    equal(a,b);

}


public static int equal(int[] a, int[] b){
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i< a.length-1;i++){

        if(a[i] == b[i]){
            j++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(j);
    return j;
}
```

Comment: With those arrays that's totally correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a nested for loop if you want to check if any single number in array `a` is also in array `b`.

e.g.

```
int numMatches = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < b.length; ++j)
    {
        if (a[i] == b[j])
            ++numMatches; //Naive, as obviously if the same number appears twice in a it'll get counted twice each time it appears in b.
    }
}
```

The current code just checks the elements at the same index match i.e

```
1 == 1 // Yes, increment j
4 == 2 // Nope
6 == 3 // Nope
7 == 4 // Nope
8 == 5 // Nope
10 == 6 // Nope
13 == 7 // Nope
```

Answer (score 8):

Your code is finding the number that are equal *at the same index.*

There are several ways you can find the size of the intersection.

**A simple but O(m*n) implementation** would be to iterate over all elements of b for each element of a.

**If the arrays are sorted,** you could use separate indexes for the two arrays, advancing each when it can no longer match. This would be O(m+n). (If they're not sorted, you could sort them first, for a cost of O(m log m + n log n ).

**If each array has no duplicate members,** another way is to compute the size of the intersection is from the size of the set difference. An example of this is at http://ideone.com/6vLAfn. The key part is to convert each array to a set, and determine how many members are in common by removing one set from another.

```
 int aSizeBefore = setA.size();
 setA.removeAll( setB );
 int aSizeAfter = setA.size();
 return aSizeBefore - aSizeAfter;
```

Answer (score 2):

Elements with same values might be in different indexes. You can write as following, assuming the arrays are sorted:

```
public static int equal(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; i < b.length - 1; j++) {

            if (a[j] < b[j]) {
                // we came to the part where all elements in b are bigger 
                // than our selected element in a
                break;
            }
            else if (a[j] == b[j]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
     }
     System.out.println(count);
     return count;
}
```

If you can't guarantee that the arrays are sorted, you can remove the if-block and remove the else-if's else from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how many numbers are present in both arrays and there is a guarantee that they are ordered, you should try the following:

```
public static int equal(int[] a, int[] b) {
        int j, result = 0;
        int lastFound = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
            for (j = lastFound; j < b.length; j++) {
                if (a[i] == b[j]) {
                    result++;
                    lastFound = j;
                    break;
                } else {
                    if (a[i] < b[j]) break;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;

    }
```

Using the variable `lastFound` will speed your loops, but it is only helpful if the arrays are ordered, as your example indicates.